# Node.js mailparser module error: Cannot find module 'iconv'

Tags: node.js, imap

I'm working on trying to learn node.js, and am playing around with [the imap and mailparser sample code found here](https://gist.github.com/1226809). I installed both [imap](https://github.com/mscdex/node-imap) and [mailparser](https://github.com/andris9/mailparser) according to the instructions in the readme documents found on their respective github pages, and everything installed fine without any errors. When attempting to run the sample code, I get the following error:

`Error: Cannot find module 'iconv'`

After installing the modules, my project directory structure looks like this:

```
~/ProjectDir
    |
    -- node_modules
    |   |
    |   -- imap
    |   |   |
    |   |   -- LICENSE
    |   |   -- README.md
    |   |   -- imap.js
    |   |   -- package.json
    |   -- mailparser
    |   |   |
    |   |   -- lib
    |   |   |   |
    |   |   |   -- datetime.js
    |   |   |   -- mailparser.js
    |   |   |   -- streams.js
    |   |   -- node_modules
    |   |   |   |
    |   |   |   -- iconv
    |   |   |   |   ...
    |   |   |   -- mimelib
    |   |   |   |   ...
    |   |   -- test
    |   |   |   ...
    |   |   -- LICENSE
    |   |   -- README.md
    |   |   -- package.json
    |   |       ...
    |   -- config.json
    |   -- mailFether.js
    |   -- readme.md
```

So, based on some of the googling that I've done for this problem, I've noticed that this "Cannot find module" error seems to be a fairly common one, but I've been able to see a consistent solution to the problem.

Is the problem here the nested `node_modules` directory in the `mailparser` folder? Should the contents of that folder actually be in the `node_modules` folder at the root of the project? Is this a project setup issue, or an environmental issue?

Comment: can you add your code ? Why are `config.json`, `mailFether.js` and `readme.md` in node_modules ? Or you forgot some `--` ?

Answer (score 2):

Just try to install the iconv module: `npm install iconv` - and take a look at the output of this command, iirc iconv builds a binary, this could fail under circumstances, then we should figure out why it's failing - but in this case one could only help if you provide the output of the install command.

> Is the problem here the nested node_modules directory in the mailparser folder?

No, this is ok, this is how npm works. All dependencies of a module are stored in a nested node_module folder.